SAML 2.0 With frontend web app and backend WCF
I have a frontend app (let's call it SP1) and backend app (WCF service, let's call it SP2), IdP would be ADFS 4.0 (Microsoft Entra Id Federated). I believe I can use WCF security Message and clientCredentialType issuedToken. Both apps are developed with .NET 4.8. I want to know if it's possible to:
Authenticate user with SAML2 SSO (or no SSO) with ADFS 4 with frontend (SP-initiated). With this issued token, frontend (SP1) would validate the user. Then this frontend uses the same token to call WCF service. For example, can we set up this token so it also includes assertion for SP2 so SP1 can also 'pass' this token to authenticate user with WCF (SP2). Or SP2 can consume this token (can decrypt it).
Of course, final user (browser) cannot interact directly with WCF service (SP2).
The single claim needed for both Service Providers (SP1 and SP2) can be the User Principal Name (UPN), email, sAMAccountName, or a similar identifier.
This would substitute a current Kerberos double hop with transport security scheme and delegations... which gives a headache or two from time to time.
Any advice or guidance is appreciated.

Do you mean that after the front-end authenticates the user, it generates a token and then uses this token to authenticate the user through wcf?

@Jiayao Yes, like implementing a custom token handler or something and forntend netcode would insert the token in the WCF cleint (somehow). From WCF client Point-of-View, Token would not arrive through SP2 URL through IdP's POST, it would arrive POSTed to SP1 HTTP Post binding. SP1 amd SP2 may be the same entityID if it's necessary (like a single SP)
